# Most efficient pairwise difference number python excluding np.nan

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix of samples (many hundred of rows) and observations (thousand of columns). The observation are integers but can be na. I stored them in a numpy array
I need to find the number of differences between all row pairs

I have a (stupid) code below:

```py
import numpy as np
import random 
cols = 10
rows = 5

possible_elements = list(range(5)) + [np.nan]
matrix = [random.choice(possible_elements) for _ in range(cols * rows)]
matrix = np.array(matrix).reshape(rows, cols)

distance_matrix = np.zeros((rows, rows))

def diff_number(x,y):
    d = x - y
    # The idetnical elements are == 0
    same = sum(d == 0)
    # The number of nas needs to be found too because we want to ignore
    # the columns containing nas.
    nas = np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(d))
    # The number of differences is:
    # number of columns which don't contain nas (pairwise) aka: cols - nas
    # minus the number of identical elements
    diff = cols - nas - same 
    return diff

# Row 1
for i in range(rows):
    # Row 2
    for j in range(i, rows):
        # Let's substract one row to the other
        diff = diff_number( matrix[i],  matrix[j])
        distance_matrix[i,j] = diff
        distance_matrix[j,i] = diff
print(distance_matrix)
```

I hate those two nested for loops. So I guess there is better way, could you help, please?

I also tried the `pairwise_distances` function from the [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html) package. It works, but I find it a bit overkill. What do you think?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on _It works, but I find it a bit overkill_? What is the problem with this overkill? is it not efficient enough?

Comment: I find that loading a big library to do this is a bit too much. If it is a good solution, I would use it though. I am sure that it can be done efficiently in numpy, can't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to remove only one of the two loops. Here is the code comparing the versions with one and two loops (I increased the size of the problem from `(10,5)` to `(100,50)` to evaluate computation time):

```
import numpy as np
import random
import time

cols, rows = 100, 50

possible_elements = list(range(5)) + [np.nan]
matrix = [random.choice(possible_elements) for _ in range(cols * rows)]
matrix = np.array(matrix).reshape(rows, cols)

t_start = time.time()
distance_matrix = np.zeros((rows, rows))
def diff_number(x,y):
    d = x - y
    # The idetnical elements are == 0
    same = sum(d == 0)
    # The number of nas needs to be found too because we want to ignore
    # the columns containing nas.
    nas = np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(d))
    # The number of differences is:
    # number of columns which don't contain nas (pairwise) aka: cols - nas
    # minus the number of identical elements
    diff = cols - nas - same 
    return diff

# Row 1
for i in range(rows):
    # Row 2
    for j in range(i, rows):
        # Let's substract one row to the other
        diff = diff_number( matrix[i],  matrix[j])
        distance_matrix[i,j] = diff
        distance_matrix[j,i] = diff
print('Timer 1: ', (time.time()-t_start), 's')

t_start = time.time()
ones = np.ones((cols,))
distance_matrix_2 = np.zeros((rows, rows))
for i in range(rows):
  # The identical elements are ==
  same = (matrix==matrix[[i],:]) @ ones
  # The number of nas needs to be found too because we want to ignore
  # the columns containing nas.
  nas = (np.isnan(matrix) | np.isnan(matrix[[i],:])) @ ones
  # The number of differences is:
  # number of columns which don't contain nas (pairwise) aka: cols - nas
  # minus the number of identical elements
  distance_matrix_2[i] = cols - nas - same
print('Timer 2: ', (time.time()-t_start), 's')

print('Matrix 1', distance_matrix)
print('Matrix 2', distance_matrix_2)

print('Matrices are equal!' if np.allclose(distance_matrix,distance_matrix_2) else 'Matrices differ!')
```

Output:

```
% python3 script.py
Timer 1:  0.3338479995727539 s
Timer 2:  0.0029990673065185547 s
Matrix 1 [[ 0. 61. 57. ... 56. 56. 50.]
 [61.  0. 54. ... 53. 53. 59.]
 [57. 54.  0. ... 53. 57. 51.]
 ...
 [56. 53. 53. ...  0. 57. 51.]
 [56. 53. 57. ... 57.  0. 56.]
 [50. 59. 51. ... 51. 56.  0.]]
Matrix 2 [[ 0. 61. 57. ... 56. 56. 50.]
 [61.  0. 54. ... 53. 53. 59.]
 [57. 54.  0. ... 53. 57. 51.]
 ...
 [56. 53. 53. ...  0. 57. 51.]
 [56. 53. 57. ... 57.  0. 56.]
 [50. 59. 51. ... 51. 56.  0.]]
Matrices are equal!
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer this @bousof ! It's a great time improvement too! It looks awesome but I don't quite understand how it works though, could you explain, please?

Comment: Did some more test and it is very fast! The sklearn pairwise_distance isn't faster than the nested loops if only one job is used. I ran a test on a matrix 200 rows x 2000 columns. The nested loop solution took 165sec, the sklearn pairwise took 220sec (maybe because they don't consider that the distance D(i,j) == D(j,i) so the nested loops compare only half the cases. Your solution does it in 1.4s. I am so pleased with that! Thanks!

Comment: Nice! That confirms that the one-line-of-code solution is not always the fastest one. You may be able to replace `@ one` by `.sum(axis=1)` in the code if it's more readable. The structure of the code is almost the same except that a whole line of the matrix is computed at each iteration. `|` is the logical OR operator. Last but not least, when comparing a matrix of size (100,50) with a vector of size (100,1), numpy automatically replicate the vector over the second dimension to be able to apply comparison.